# Problems multicast receive packets

Tags: linux-device-driver

I create a network device, with the possibility of multicasting dev->flags = IFF_MULTICAST.

I send a UDP message, but when I receive a packet, I don´t receive a udp message the system trace is

```
   ipv6_rcv()
    |--> ip6_route_input()
          |-->ip6_mc_input()
```

The value returned by ipv6_chk_mcast_addr() in function ip6_mc_input() is 0.
I think I need to add the multicast address ff02::2 in the mc_list.

This is true?

How do I make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the multicast group to receive traffic on it.  The `IFF_MULTICAST` flag means that your device (driver) supports multicast.  The driver is expected to configure the hardware (often just a filter) when the system wants to join or leave a multicast group.

Since you're passing packets up the stack, either your hardware is pretty promiscuous by default, or you've somehow configured the hardware filter without the system having joined the multicast group.

Whatever the case may be, in order for `ipv6_chk_mcast_addr()` to succeed, you'll have to join the destination multicast group.  From userspace, you'd do this with the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` `setsockopt()` call.  Since you're interested in the all-routers multicast group (ff02::2), I believe (but can't remember for certain) that the kernel will join it automatically when you configure forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve my problem. I need to make a socket like this.

```
if ((sockEnvio = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))){

        printf("socket() failed");

    }

 // Bind the socket to the interface we're interested in
    int err=0;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("eth2");
    server.sin6_port = htons(15118);
    err = bind(sockEnvio, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("packet socket bind return failed:");
        close(sockEnvio);     
    }
    printf("ICMPv6 socket bind to interface %d OK", if_nametoindex("eth2")); //if_nametoindex(lan));

   int optval = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_RECVPKTINFO, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
        perror("Error! setsockopt(IPV6_RECVPKTINFO)"); 
        close(sockEnvio);

    }

   optval = 0;
    if (setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, &optval, sizeof(optval)) <0 ) {
        perror("Error! setsockopt(IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP)");
        close(sockEnvio);

    }

    struct ipv6_mreq mreq;
    memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq));
    mreq.ipv6mr_interface = if_nametoindex("eth2");
    mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[ 0] = 0xff;
    mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[ 1] = 0x02;
    mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[15] = 0x02;
    if (setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("Error! setsockopt(IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ff02::02)");
        close(sockEnvio);       
    }
```